Remote port API showing 'network request failed' in React Native
I'm using a remote port API to retrieve data, however the error message is 'network request failed'. We get the data on the web browser and in Postman, however it does not work in React Native.
Note: My API is a remote API (no SSL), not a localhost API.
Please check my code:
fetch('https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50000/b1s/v1/Login', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'          
  },
  body: '',
  }).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    console.log(responseJson)
  }).catch((error) => {  
    console.error(error);
  });

I have tried android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" but it's still not working. Without making SSL is there any way to call that API? please help me. I am unable to find any solution.
